# Solving an algorithm math problem

Tags: arithmetic, cryptarithm

if x, y and z each represent a different digit from 0 to 9, what is the value of (x)(y)(z)?

```
 4z
 27
+x5
____

y14
```

I answered it like this:

```
 42
 27
+45
____

114
```

So x=4, y=1 and z=2 for a total of 7.  But I got it wrong because the correct answer is 8.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(x)(y)(z) means multiplication of the three, and (4)(1)(2) is 8.

Answer (score 0):

You computed the sum $x+y+z$ where the problem asked for the product $x\times y\times z$.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I had to be overthinking it.  Been studying for a test and I am just burnt out! :-)